# Count Change Example in Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs section on Tree Recursion

Tags: algorithm, recursion, computer-science, sicp, coin-change

In section 1.2.2 of the classic text Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs, there is an example of how to count the number of ways to break an amount of money into smaller denominations. Here is the language they wrote:

> It takes only a bit of cleverness to come up with the iterative
>   Fibonacci algorithm. In contrast, consider the following problem: How
>   many different ways can we make change of $1.00, given half-dollars,
>   quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies? More generally, can we write a
>   procedure to compute the number of ways to change any given amount of
>   money?
>
> This problem has a simple solution as a recursive procedure. Suppose
>   we think of the types of coins available as arranged in some order.
>   Then the following relation holds:
>
> The number of ways to change amount *a* using *n* kinds of coins equals...
>
> ...the number of ways to change amount *a* using all but the first kind of
>   coin, plus the number of ways to change amount *a − d* using all *n* kinds
>   of coins, where *d* is the denomination of the first kind of coin.
>
> To see why this is true, observe that the ways to make change can be
>   divided into two groups: those that do not use any of the first kind
>   of coin, and those that do. Therefore, the total number of ways to
>   make change for some amount is equal to the number of ways to make
>   change for the amount without using any of the first kind of coin,
>   plus the number of ways to make change assuming that we do use the
>   first kind of coin. But the latter number is equal to the number of
>   ways to make change for the amount that remains after using a coin of
>   the first kind.

My question is about the last statement. We're talking about a dollar (though they later recommend trying to solve this with a smaller amount such as 10 cents) - *why exactly is it* that the number of ways to break a dollar is always equal to the number of ways to break the amount that remains after removing a single coin of one denomination from a dollar (i.e. a dollar less the amount of an individual coin)?

Comment: I'm not sure if this shouldn't be on computer science stackexchange https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have all the ways of making a dollar change and we choose any denomination, let's say a quater (25c). We can go through the solutions spliting them between that use a quater and those that don't:

"All solutions for $1" = "solutions for $1 that use a quater" + "solutions for $1 that don't use a quater"

The authors are claiming "All solutions for $1 that use a quater" is the same Size as "all solutions for 75c".  You may inuitively see this is true.  Formally you can say:

a) "solutions for $1 that use a quater" <= "all solutions for 75c" because for each "Solutions for $1 that uses a quater" you can remove the quater and get a solution for 75c.

b) "all solutions for 75c" <= "Solutions for $1 that use a quater" because for each solution for 75c you can add a quater and get a solution that is in "Solutions for $1 that use a quater".

So they must be the same size, i.e.:

```
Size of "solutions for $1 that use a quater" 
    = Size of "all solutions for 75c"
```

so:

```
Size of "All solutions for $1" = 
    Size of "solutions for $1 that use a quater"
    + Size of "solutions for $1 that don't use a quater"
```

Can be rewritten as:

```
Size of "All solutions" = 
    Size of "all solutions for 75c"
    + Size of "solutions for $1 that don't use a quater"
```